# Fetching 'action_name' or 'controller' from helper spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bdd

Let's say that I have the following code in **application_helper.rb**:

```
def do_something
 if action_name == 'index'
   'do'
 else
   'dont'
 end
end
```

which will do something if called within index action.

Q: How do I rewrite the helper spec for this in **application_helper_spec.rb** to simulate a call from 'index' action?

```
describe 'when called from "index" action' do
  it 'should do' do
    helper.do_something.should == 'do' # will always return 'dont'
  end
end

describe 'when called from "other" action' do
  it 'should do' do
    helper.do_something.should == 'dont'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can stub action_name method to whatever value you want:

```
describe 'when called from "index" action' do
  before
    helper.stub!(:action_name).and_return('index')
  end
  it 'should do' do
    helper.do_something.should == 'do'
  end
end

describe 'when called from "other" action' do
  before
    helper.stub!(:action_name).and_return('other')
  end
  it 'should do' do
    helper.do_something.should == 'dont'
  end
end
```

Comment: stub! at helper, damn missed trying that out, I did stub!(:action_name).and_return('index'), not helper.stub!(:action_name).and_return('index')

Thanks rsim :)